# Regex XOR with multiple words

Tags: .net, regex, xor

I would like to know if it is possible to have a regex that will check if 0 or on 1 of an array of words are present in a string. An exclusive OR with multiple entries...

Words that the string can contain 0 or only 1 :

- Morning
- Evening
- Night

The following sentences should give the following result :

1. This is a beautiful day => match (0 of the words)
2. How are you this Morning ? => match (1 of the words)
3. This Morning, it was the Night ! => not match (1 of the words)
4. This Night, we will have a wonderful Morning => not match (2 of the words or more)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The pure regex solution should be something along the lines of:

```
string words = string.Join("|", yourWordsArray);
string regex = "^(?!.*\b(" + words + ")\b.*\b(" + words + ")\b).*\b(" + words + ")\b.*$";
```

**/Edit**

What you are asking is a "find every string that has NOT > 1 matches". In .Net this is rather easy, as you can have a construction like this:

`return !(Regex.Matches("your text", "your regex").Count > 1)`

and your regex would be something like:`

```
string regex = string.Join("|", yourWordsArray);
```

Not the prettiest of all code, but could be worse

Comment: Thank you for the .Net tips, however I have a generic Regex validator, so I have to find a way to solve it using a regex and not using C# tips to solve my issue. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I assumed you were since you used the .net tag. I will try to conjure up a regex for you.

Comment: If it can help, I will always have 3 exclusive words, but for my personnal training, I will be happy to see a more generic way to solve that case :-)

Comment: Assuming that you need your answer as soon as possible I will for now link you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8764935/2935464 which has a nice post about it